how to do efficiently element wise multiplication of two matrices in r
I want to do elementwise multiplication of two large matrices, i want to do it the most efficiently possible.
Currently i am using the base operator *
For example if i have a DF1 like the next:



A
B




1
2


3
4



and a DF2 like the next:



X
Y




5
6


7
8



DF1*DF2 results in



X
Y




5
12


21
32



how can i make it faster?

base * operator is that slow?

The names DF1 and DF2 suggest that you have data frames, not matrices. If they were actually matrices the multiplication would be faster so use as.matrix to first convert each of them to matrices and then do the multiplication.

Below are several possible options, and you can choose the one you like.
For speed, you can try the method in f3()
set.seed(0)
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
B <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))

f1 <- function() A * B
f2 <- function() as.data.frame(as.matrix(A) * as.matrix(B))
f3 <- function() as.data.frame(`dim<-`(unlist(A, FALSE, FALSE) * unlist(B, FALSE, FALSE), dim(A)))
f4 <- function() list2DF(Map(`*`, A, B))

microbenchmark(
    f1(),
    f2(),
    f3(),
    f4(),
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative"
)

and you will see
Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
 f1() 19.315789 18.795854 9.927453 16.090020 14.320574 1.0078119   100
 f2()  5.318182  5.192839 3.243506  4.736301  4.274322 0.7957232   100
 f3()  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.0000000   100
 f4()  3.533493  3.342965 2.057707  2.988258  2.640750 0.6603172   100


If you don't need to keep both A and B, you can update one of them by reference with collapse::setop, which will be faster than any base version of A*B. The time differences are more apparent with larger matrices:
library(collapse)

set.seed(0)
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e4), 100, 100))
B <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e4), 100, 100))

f1 <- function() A * B
f2 <- function() as.data.frame(as.matrix(A) * as.matrix(B))
f3 <- function() as.data.frame(`dim<-`(unlist(A, FALSE, FALSE) * unlist(B, FALSE, FALSE), dim(A)))
f4 <- function() list2DF(Map(`*`, A, B))
f5 <- function() setop(AA, "*", B)

For the benchmark, we have to add setup = {AA <- A*1} because AA is updated by reference each time f5 is called.
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1(),
  f2(),
  f3(),
  f4(),
  f5(),
  setup = {AA <- A*1},
  check = "equal",
  unit = "relative"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>  expr       min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>  f1() 246.80887 269.968102 229.09017 334.57839 333.18018 16.703191   100
#>  f2()  53.29693  51.886762  46.97326  52.85084  75.09009  6.544267   100
#>  f3()  10.31741   9.972887  12.58650  10.11263  13.70399 16.416862   100
#>  f4()  35.90785  34.858054  36.90257  38.21005  57.01931  5.161036   100
#>  f5()   1.00000   1.000000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000  1.000000   100

